# How do I plot multiple series with different x-values in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

How do I plot multiple series with different x-values in Pandas? I expect the following to work but it seems to produce multiple figures.

```
rawdat.plot(x='ts', y=['bid','ask'], marker='.', lw=0)
plot.hold()
rawdat.plot(x='lastTrade', y='last', marker='x', lw=0)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to tell `matplotlib` through the `pandas.plot` interface that you want the plots on the same `axis` [(see docs)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
ax = rawdat.plot(x='ts', y=['bid','ask'], marker='.', lw=0)
plot.hold()
rawdat.plot(x='lastTrade', y='last', marker='x', lw=0, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```